# any harm in put django request object in thread local dict?

Tags: django, request, thread-local

I have some custom `render_to_response` methods which now needs request object, I could pass request to each one of them but instead I am saving request object in a middleware to thread local space and accessing it elsewhere, can it affect me anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any. Here you should find everything you need:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser